# Are stratigraphic tags useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have found myself in the last few months tagging or retagging some questions with time-based tags (namely [precambrian](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precambrian) and [carboniferous](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carboniferous)). I realize now that nobody else did, and thus was wondering what is the community thought on them: do you think there is a need for them?

The reason I added them (and therefore think they are needed) is that I often look (on Google Scholar for instance) for epoch-specific information and thus limit my search using stratigraphic terms, and I naturally thought of doing the same here eventually.

Comment: I agree, and think this is actually a very important step to take to better index the questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely a good idea. Paleoscience is huge, and having multiple ways to split it up (by period, discipline, etc.) is going to make it easier for people with diverse interests to find relevant questions.